# Convert characters to octal, binary, and integer

Tags: c++, serialization, number-systems

I have implemented a sample program that converts vector of characters to its integer representation depending on the bit size specified. I was hoping to get some input on how to simplify the sequence. I think my approach is convoluted.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int OctalToBinary(int octalNum) {
    int decimalNum = 0, binaryNum = 0, count = 0;

    while (octalNum != 0) {
        decimalNum += (octalNum % 10) * pow(8, count);
        ++count;
        octalNum /= 10;
    }
    count = 1;
    while (decimalNum != 0) {
        binaryNum += (decimalNum % 2) * count;
        decimalNum /= 2;
        count *= 10;
    }
    return binaryNum;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> buffer = { '3','7','4','3','0'};
    std::vector<int> bitsize = { 3,3,8 };
    std::vector<char> collection;
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    // convert characters to octal and 

    for each ( char c in buffer)
    {
        int x = c - '0';
        std::stringstream opt;
        opt << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << OctalToBinary(x) << "\n";

        std::string val = opt.str();

        std::copy(val.begin(), val.end()-1, std::back_inserter(collection));
    }

    int start_index = 0;
    int end_index = 0;

    // convert binary values to integer
    for (int i = 0; i < bitsize.size(); i++)
    {
        start_index = end_index;
        end_index += bitsize[i];

        std::string temporary_string(collection.begin() + start_index, collection.begin() + end_index);
        int converted_integer = std::stoi(temporary_string.c_str(), nullptr, 2);
        std::cout << temporary_string << " " << converted_integer << "\n";
    }

    // output should be 3, 7 , 140

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Unnecessary Headers**
The #includes for iterator and bitset are not needed, the code compiles fine without them, iterator may be included indirectly through vector.

Adding unnecessary headers can increase compile/build times and may cause other problems in larger more complex programs.

**Portability**
This program is currently not portable for 2 reasons, the use of the Visual Studio generated `#include "stdafx.h"` and the use of the non-standard for each loop. It might be better to embed `#include "stdafx.h"` within ifdef/endif.

```
#ifdef windows
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

I compiled this in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 and it actually reported a compile error on the for each loop. The suggested fix was to use a range based for loop.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: octbinintconv0, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>octbinintconv0.cpp
1>d:\projectsnfwsi\codereview\octbinintconv0\octbinintconv0\octbinintconv0.cpp(18): warning C4244: '+=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>d:\projectsnfwsi\codereview\octbinintconv0\octbinintconv0\octbinintconv0.cpp(40): error C4496: nonstandard extension 'for each' used: replace with ranged-for statement
1>d:\projectsnfwsi\codereview\octbinintconv0\octbinintconv0\octbinintconv0.cpp(55): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>Done building project "octbinintconv0.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

You might want to replace the `for each` loop with the following code, which uses an iterator and is part of standard C++.

```
    for (auto c : buffer)
    {
        int x = c - '0';
        std::stringstream opt;
        opt << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << OctalToBinary(x) << "\n";

        std::string val = opt.str();

        std::copy(val.begin(), val.end() - 1, std::back_inserter(collection));
    }
```

**Type Mismatches**
A good practice is treating warning messages as errors, since they point to potential logic errors. The `pow()` function returns double and the result is being truncated, it might be better to use a static cast in the code to show that this is intentional.

```
    decimalNum += (octalNum % 10) * static_cast<int>(pow(8, count));
```

In this for loop it would be better to define the local variable `i` as `size_t` rather than int, in any of the STL container classes the function `size()` returns size_t.

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bitsize.size(); i++)
```

**Complexity**
Creating the function `OctalToBinary(int octalNum)` was good but there are two more functions that `main()` can be broken up into, they have even been identified by comments, both of the for loop are good candidates for functions.